# Modifying appointment event from external using Javascript

Tags: fullcalendar

I am working ith Fullcalendar, and it is great. I now want to use SignalR to modify events in real time. For this i would need to modify a single event and render it.

In the API section it gives me the way for dealing with drag and drop. this and creating the schedules etc. have been working in my development since 4 years without issue.

Does anybody please have an idea or snippet how to initiate a call to modify/create/delete a calendar item from external (how to create an instance with which ID, server will not know the schedule ID, and just rerender this one instance which is shown in the API section)

thanxs

Walter

Comment: You can create a new event on the calendar using https://fullcalendar.io/docs/renderEvent - you simply pass in an event object. To create multiple events at once you can use https://fullcalendar.io/docs/renderEvents, or alternatively you could create an array of events and then add them as an event source using https://fullcalendar.io/docs/addEventSource . Beyond that I'm not really clear what you're asking for?

Comment: And of course there's https://fullcalendar.io/docs/updateEvent if you want to change an existing event

Comment: HI, I have checked the samples, and usign my mouse to move them and run the events thats fine, I want to change the schedules without any human interaction, only by a call from a JS function wwhich is called from the server by SignalR. I am not sure how i can get the instance of the perticular schedule Item, I Assume i would need to loop through them, but i was just curious what would be the best way to search for my perticular item using just JS to get the instance of my calendar item

Comment: Perhaps you should take some time to study the fullCalendar documentation in a bit more detail. If you want to get hold of an existing calendar item which is currently held in fullCalendar's memory, use https://fullcalendar.io/docs/clientEvents - you can specify the ID of the item you want, or provide a callback to filter the results in any other way you choose.

Comment: OK, thanx, so I can get hold of a single schedule, using the client Events, which is great, but just did not strike me, since i was not looking for an event, but a property to reference a single schedule. Thanx

Comment: fullCalendar does not use that word to mean anything (except in the title of the "Scheduler" plugin, but nowhere else). If you were searching in the API for "schedule" when you should have been searching for "event" then I can see why you didn't find anything useful. Do you need any further help?

Comment: No thnx, got it figured out, i  can parse all objects im memory and recieve my instance of schedule, modify it and then render it